# How to avoid the if statement inside a loop, after some value get reached

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, mcmc

I'm struggling on how my code could stop pass by the "if statement" when `rate` reach some desired value. Here is some kind of pseudo algorithm (if the code is not clear I can try to change, since it is very clear to me, that is too 'inside' the problem).

```
for(i in 1:500){
  if(i %% 100 == 0){
    cte = cte * A #value of A differs according the `rate` value 
  }
  A = function(A)
  rate = function(A, cte)  
}
```

If `rate` reach certain value, e.g, `if 0.15 < rate < 0.3`, I'd like to never come back to the `if` statement. Even if the `rate` goes out of that range along the 'for loop', I don't go back to the 'if'.

Any hint on how can I do that?

Comment: You want to add something else to your condition. So your if would be `if(i %% 100 == 0 & ! between(rate, 0.15, 0.3))`

Comment: But I want that after the first time the rate reach the value between(rate, 0.15, 0.3), I never use the `if` statement again.

Comment: TRUE & FALSE evaluates to FALSE and the condition is not run

Comment: Yes, but the for-loop keeps running, and the rate could  goes out of the range (0.15, 0.3), and I don't want that `cte` get update anymore, since it reach the desired range once.

Comment: Aaah, ok! Use `break` when the condition is reached

Comment: Can I break the if and keep the for-loop?

Comment: No. `break` is for exiting the for-loop. You don't "break out of the if". Whenever the loop is run, the condition is evaluated. IF it is TRUE, the code in the if statement runs. If it is FALSE, it doesn't. That is the whole purpose of an if-statement

Comment: Right! That's my issue! How to avoid the `if` after I got the desired rate once.

Comment: You don't. If you add what I said before to the if statement, it will always evaluate to false once the condition is reached

Answer (score 0):

You need a variable to track your state:

```
rate_was_within_bounds = FALSE
for(i in 1:500){
  if(i %% 100 == 0 & !rate_was_within_bounds){
    cte = cte * A #value of A differs according the `rate` value 
  }
  A = function(A)
  rate = function(A, cte)  
  if (0.15 < rate & rate < 0.3) {
    rate_was_within_bounds = TRUE
  }
}
```